# Do SQL Server Transaction Logs get 'locked' when there is a non-zero log_reuse_wait?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

**Scenario:**

I have an application attempting to write to a SQL Server DB, and I'm getting the message:

> The transaction log for database 'DB_NAME' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

However, I see that there is plenty of space on the drive for the transaction log to be written and autogrowth is on.  So from SQL Management Studio, I issue:

```
select name,
    log_reuse_wait,
    log_reuse_wait_desc
  from sys.databases 
  where name = 'DB_NAME'
```

and can see that the log_reuse_wait is '3'.

**Question:**

Do SQL Server transaction logs get 'locked' in any way when this wait is in place?

Note that this is set to 'Simple' recover model.  Please let me know if there is more information I need to provide to make this a complete question.

Comment: How is auto-growth configured on this database's log? Is there a maximum? Is there enough space for the next auto-growth increment? Double-check that the disk the log file is on has the space you're referring to. Also, double-check that auto-shrink is not on.

Comment: Also: in the Simple recovery model, as soon as a transaction is finished, its log space is released for reuse. If the log file is at its upper limit, then it could fill up while a transaction is running, generate the log full error, roll back the transaction, and then leave plenty of available log space. However, unless you are manually shrinking the log file, or have auto-shrink turned on, the log file would continue to take up as much disk space as it had grown to consume.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Have you validated that the autogrowth setting is not only on, but correct? There was a bug where this value would get reset to some astronomical number, and the growth wouldn't be possible because disks simply aren't that big. Also, `log_reuse_wait = 3` means "Active backup or restore" - have you checked into that?

Comment: Do you have any in-memory objects?  If you do, one fix is to detach the database, attach it back and quickly, literally within a minute, run a checkpoint and truncate.  Do you see any 9002 errors in the application event log or sql errorlog?

Comment: I **do not recommend** detaching the database - what if you can't attach it again?

Comment: I will not be detaching the database.

Comment: Autogrowth is unrestricted.  Autoshrink is set to False.  SQL Server 2008.  I'm aware of what the wait is caused by (message-wise), but even if this was going on, wouldn't the transaction log be usable if it had sufficient free space?

Comment: Assuming you've taken a backup and perhaps tested a restore and checkdb, killing any connections to the database and then checkpointing may be a start. However you resolve this, it would be interesting to get a summary.